# Equivalence and Order Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have the following problem: *Provide an example of a set $S$ and a relation $\sim$ on $S$ such that $\sim$ is both an equivalence relation and an order relation.  Conjecture for which sets and this is possible, and prove your conjecture.*

Below is the example I came up with but I don't know how to prove my conjecture and I don't even know if I am correct, I would really appreciate some help!

The only set that satisfies the reflexive property of an equivalence relation and the nonreflexive property of an order relation is the $\emptyset$.  For any relation on that set, it is vacuously true that is is both an equivalence relation and an order relation.

Comment: Have you looked at $\mathbf{Z}$, or perhaps $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ as possible sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your order relations are required to be strict (that is, irreflexive), then you're almost done.

You have already shown that $\varnothing$ has an appropriate relation. What remains is to show that no *nonempty* set can have a relation that is both an equivalence and an order.

Thus assume that $A$ is a set, $x\in A$ (such an $x$ will exist if $A$ is nonempty), and $R\subseteq A^2$ is a relation on $A$, and that $R$ is a equivalence relation, *and* that $R$ is a (partial?) order. Use these assumptions to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows: Let $S$ be a nonempty set. Set $$\sim:=\{(x,x)\mid x\in S\}.$$ That is, $\sim$ is just the diagonal of $S\times S.$  Then $\sim$ is clearly reflexive. The transitivity and symmetry and antisymmetry of $\sim$ is surely vacuously true.  In conclusion, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $S,$ so is a partial order relation.